# iOS Getting the value from a TextView in xCode

Tags: xcode

I am trying to write a master detail application and I have a TextView and whatever the user enters in the TextView, becomes the new item. But whenever I press the add button it crashes the program with error: object cannot be nil

Here is my code:

```
@interface MasterViewController () {
   NSMuteableArray *_objects;
   IBOutlet UITextView *text;
}
```

And at Insert New Object method I have this:

```
[_objects insertObject:text.text atIndex:0];
```

Do I need to hook it up to my actual TextView somehow?

Any help would be amazing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Make sure you actually wired that outlet up to the TextView
- Make sure you allocated that NSMutableArray somewhere

  _objects = [[MSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: I have allocated that NsMutableArray, how do I wire that outlet up to the TextView? Sorry I am new to iOS! Do I just need to make a new property in the header file?

Comment: Yes.  Better yet, use the Assistant Editor for doing that.  If that is new to you, Google it.  Learning how to use the AE will change your life :)

Comment: Would you be able to give me the syntax for wiring it up? Thank you so much!

Comment: That isn't really a syntax thing.  That is something you do with your mouse/trackpad.

Comment: I know I drag into somewhere whilst holding Ctrl, but into which class?

Comment: The parent class of the view controller